# What were the other A.I. chips and whom are they referring to?

Tags: reference, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In Age of Ultron, Iron man selected the FRIDAY chip from the rest for the replacement of J.A.R.V.I.S

[image]

I was clearly able to find out references to [Jocasta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jocasta_%28comics%29) and [FRIDAY](http://marvel.wikia.com/Friday_(Earth-616)). What are the rest of the chips for? Are they also some Easter eggs?

Comment: I think you'd be better answered on SciFi.SE which can give you reference from comics too.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 there is no rule that you can't cite comics here... More people there may be conversant with them there but they are perfectly fine as reference material.

Comment: @Catija That site has more experts in this field..

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 So? I just said that, too. By your logic, this site would be devoid of all sci-fi and fantasy questions, which is absurd.

Comment: @Catija This is poor that we've overlaps..

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 In overlap cases, its always asker's decision where he want to post it.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Okay. Then, I suggest you to transfer this question to SFF.SE. I bet you can get better answer there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I’ve re-watched that scene quite carefully, and I can only make out the names of three AI chips:

- **Friday** – referring to the Marvel Comics AI character [of the same name](http://marvel.wikia.com/Friday_(Earth-616)), who was created by Tony when the hassle of hiring a human secretary became too much. Named because she was his “Girl Friday” (meaning a faithful assistant or servant).

  [image]
- **Jocasta** – referring to the Marvel Comics AI character [of the same name](http://marvel.wikia.com/Jocasta_(Earth-616)), who was created when Ultron brainwashed Henry Pym (Ultron’s creator in the comics) into creating a wife. She was based on Pym’s wife, Janet van Dyne (aka the Wasp).

  [image]
- **Tadashi** – referring to the Marvel Comics character [of the same name](http://marvel.wikia.com/Tadashi_Hamada_(Earth-14123)), who created the robot Baymax. He may be more familiar as a character in the Disney film *Big Hero 6*, which was based on the story from the comics.

  [image]

  (I’m not totally sure this is correct, but I’ve seen several people float this theory, and it looks plausible given the fragment we see.)

There are at least five AI chips on the table, but I can’t make out the names of the other two.

Comment: +1, i almost got to Tadashi too but didn't have any clear screenshot then your. Will wait a bit more if someone can come up with others.

Comment: `three AI chips` That's all that are ever visible (BR release)

Comment: The original reference for "Friday" was a character in *Robinson Crusoe*.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm very late to the party, but the 4th computer chip seems to read "HAL", as in the AI from 2001 space odyssey. I doubt there is another pop-culture AI which shares these last 3 letters.

[image]

Comment: Looks partially obscured and as if it could have something before the "HAL" (if indeed it does say that).

Comment: Considering how all the others are references to other famous AI's HAL is a safe bet.

Comment: a safe bet, but not definite as your answer seems to indicate. Could be worth changing to "but the 4th computer chip seems to read HAL".

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking ABIGAIL is the most likely for the obscured chip.
I also considered DARYL and HAL but they didn't fit as closely.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bOp6xNWs_HPPK5U75HzsjQ0tPQ5cOG_H/view?usp=sharing

Also I think the most likely chip flipped upside down should be Karen(for spiderman's suit) in lore though the writers probably haden't thought of that yet 2year release date difference. EDITH is even further out.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bP4lEqf0SHalcZZ0VBvC5qtIRTqsgGwI/view?usp=sharing
He has also been known to have
H.O.M.E.R.
P.L.A.T.O.
V.I.R.G.I.L
Veronica

Comment: Can you indicate what the links you provided link to? If they link to images, could you maybe upload them through the editor? And if it's text, please edit the relevant information into your answer.

Comment: An error occurs when I try to upload the pictures.