# How many AIs have been made by Tony Stark in the MCU?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

Tony Stark has made JARVIS and FRIDAY in the MCU.

1. How many other in-universe AIs have been made by him?

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron* it is seen that he chooses FRIDAY from a set of different AIs.

2. What were the name of those AIs?
3. So, what is the total number of AI assistants made by him in the
   MCU, not in comics?

Comment: 1. So far, that's it. 2.. You can see some of their names (2 as I remember) at the scene when Tony selecting the AI modules,prior to last battle 3. So far,as we seen, 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than "Jarvis" and "Friday", there are at least **THREE** other *named* AIs and possibly several other unnamed ones.

Two of which are seen in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*

These are JOCASTA & TADASHI as detailed in this earlier M&TV Q&A: [What were the other A.I. chips and who are they referring to?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33907/what-were-the-other-a-i-chips-and-whom-are-they-referring-to).

*Note that there are at least TWO other chips seen but the labeling (and hence the names) are not seen.*

Since then we have seen *Spider-Man: Homecoming* which also features an AI, which apparently was not given a name by Stark but is called "Karen / Suit Lady" by Peter Parker.

---

*Spider-Man: Far From Home* also features another AI (apparently) named E.D.I.T.H. which can remotely access a network of security drones and is accessed via a pair of high-tech glasses first seen in *Captain America: Civil War*.

EDITH is said to stand for "**E**ven **D**ead **I**'m **T**he **H**ero".

Comment: Isn't Karen/Suit Lady some kind of extension to JARVIS? different voice and all may be, but I remember something about that

Comment: There's no indication of that as far as I am aware. Jarvis *no longer exists* having been subsumed into Vision.

Comment: @Paulie_D Can Falcon's Redwing be considered as an AI-assisted drone that was built by Tony Stark?

Answer (score 1):

While he needed help to do it, he of course also created Vision and Ultron.

Veronica does not seem to be classed as a full AI by the [MCU's Wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Veronica), which describes it as a 'mobile service module deployed from a space satellite... stocked with automatic assembled parts of the Iron Man Armor: Mark XLIV for real time customization of the Hulkbuster armor and versatile combat capability, as well as walls of a self assembled electrified cage whose sum form a containment prison".

Comment: vision is actually a combination of JARVIS and mind stone. Neither Stark nor banner actually created ultron, but mind stone did(kinda). Veronica isn't an AI but a failsafe hulkbuster armor supply which he and banner created to follow Stark's commands. anyways, fandom information are not considered a good sources AFAIK.

Comment: @Vishwa - I get what you are saying which is why I why I included the caveat 'While he needed help to do it...' - BANNER: 'Your mind is  >*made*< up of a complex construct of overlays. J.A.R.V.I.S., Ultron, >*Tony*<, me, the Stone. All of them mixed together'

Comment: plus - it doesnt help when you change the question from 'how many AI's' has Tony made to how many AI 'assistants' in a subsequent edit, which of course does not include Vision or Ultron :-(

Comment: I didn't change anything in the question, my edit is just about formatting. I separated questions from the paragraph and made'em into numbering format

Comment: Sorry - my mistake - I never noticed the specification of 'AI assistants' when I first answered and as such my answer is completely wrong.

Comment: not completely..

Comment: @StephenFrancis: If you think your answer is wrong, you should probably delete it (or edit it to answer the question).